# Magento Coupon Codes Not showing up in Report

Tags: error, coupon, code

I have set up various coupon codes in Magento, all work ok. However not all of them show up in the 'Coupon Usage Reports' page. They have all been made exactly the same way. Why is this?

Comment: Have you check concole or magento log file when you open report page?

Answer (score 0):

Please refresh lifetime statistic

Reports > Statistics> Refresh Statistics then check Coupon click refresh lifetime statistic and Submit.
It may be take some time depend on your data.
Then create again coupon report.